# Issue running Java in VS Code

Tags: java, visual-studio, visual-studio-code

I'm having the following issue with running a simple java program on vs code. I installed JDK, and other languages like python work just fine. Any answers?

```
Program 'launcher.bat' failed to run: The system cannot find the file specifiedAt 
line:1 char:2
+  & 'c:\Users\solwo\.vscode\extensions\vscjava.vscode-java-debug-0.36. ...
+  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~.
At line:1 char:2
+  & 'c:\Users\solwo\.vscode\extensions\vscjava.vscode-java-debug-0.36. ...
+  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ResourceUnavailable: (:) [], ApplicationFailedException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandFailed
```

Comment: Reinstall extension or [reset vscode](https://code.visualstudio.com/Docs/setup/setup-overview#_how-can-i-do-a-clean-uninstall-of-vs-code), does it help?

Comment: Tried both. Did not work. Any other suggestions?

Comment: Change the default terminal. If the error still exists, please file issue report in [github/vscode-java-debug](https://github.com/microsoft/java-debug/issues).